# Use VBA to add multiple fields to one record while also adding a category to each field

Tags: vba, ms-access, dropdown

I could not find the answer to this question elsewhere.  I am a new VBA user.

I have a very simple form for entering data on plant specimens.  There are only 3 fields that have drop down boxes.  Two fields, "Species" and "Code" reference information from another table called "MasterVegList" to facilitate field data entry.

In order to allow the end user to add new species into to the form and the "MasterVegList" table, I wrote the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub Code_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
Dim strTmp As String

    'Get confirmation that this is not just a spelling error.
    strTmp = "Add '" & NewData & "' as a new category?"
    If MsgBox(strTmp, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion, "Not in list") = vbYes Then

        'Append the NewData as a record in the Categories table.
        strTmp = "INSERT INTO MasterVegList ( Code ) " & _
            "SELECT """ & NewData & """ AS Code;"
        DBEngine(0)(0).Execute strTmp, dbFailOnError

        'Notify Access about the new record, so it requeries the combo.
        Response = acDataErrAdded
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Species_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
Dim strTmp As String

    'Get confirmation that this is not just a spelling error.
    strTmp = "Add '" & NewData & "' as a new category?"
    If MsgBox(strTmp, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion, "Not in list") = vbYes Then

        'Append the NewData as a record in the Categories table.
        strTmp = "INSERT INTO MasterVegList ( Species ) " & _
            "SELECT """ & NewData & """ AS Species;"
        DBEngine(0)(0).Execute strTmp, dbFailOnError

        'Notify Access about the new record, so it requeries the combo.
        Response = acDataErrAdded
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that when a new species is entered, a new record is created for both species and code in the MasterVegList table.  I need both species and code to be entered into the same record.  Please note that I am referring to the MasterVegList table, not the table meant to be populated using the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prompt the user for the code if a new species is entered, or the species if a new code is entered:

```
Private Sub Code_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
Dim strTmp As String

    'Get confirmation that this is not just a spelling error.
    strTmp = "Add '" & NewData & "' as a new category?"
    If MsgBox(strTmp, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion, "Not in list") = vbYes Then
        Dim strInput As String
        strInput = InputBox("What's the species?")
        'Append the NewData as a record in the Categories table.
        strTmp = "INSERT INTO MasterVegList ( Code, Species ) " & _
            "VALUES(""" & NewData  & """, """ & strInput  & """);"
        CurrentDb.Execute strTmp, dbFailOnError

        'Notify Access about the new record, so it requeries the combo.
        Response = acDataErrAdded
        Me.Species.Requery
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Species_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
Dim strTmp As String

    'Get confirmation that this is not just a spelling error.
    strTmp = "Add '" & NewData & "' as a new category?"
    If MsgBox(strTmp, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion, "Not in list") = vbYes Then
        Dim strInput As String
        strInput = InputBox("What's the code?")
        'Append the NewData as a record in the Categories table.
        strTmp = "INSERT INTO MasterVegList ( Code, Species ) " & _
            "VALUES(""" & strInput  & """, """ & NewData  & """);"
        CurrentDb.Execute strTmp, dbFailOnError

        'Notify Access about the new record, so it requeries the combo.
        Response = acDataErrAdded
        Me.Code.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

You probably want to check that the user actually enters a valid input, but I'm leaving that as an exercise for the reader.

I've also changed the following things: use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` instead of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, and use `CurrentDb` instead of `DbEngine(0)(0)`

Also, you might want to parameterize those queries, so people are able to enter quotes in the fields.